# How to autofill svn commit message based on merge information

Tags: svn

Short: How can I fill a svn commit message automatically based on merge informations?

Long: I want to build the following workflow **for the svn command line client only** (I know it exists for TortoisveSVN)

1. svn merge -c5,7 ^/branches/MyBranch localTrunkWC
2. svn commit localTrunkWC
   The commit message should now be autofilled with:

   ```
   Merged from ^/branches/myBranch revision r5, r7
   COMMIT MESSAGE FROM r5 SHOULD BE AUTOFILLED HERE
   COMMIT MESSAGE FROM r7 SHOULD BE AUTOFILLED HERE
   ```

Comment: You can't do it in pure SVN. Duplication of commit messages in mergeset is **The Bad Idea (tm)**

Comment: I know it is not possible using pure svn, but I hope there is some easy or already existing solution to this. Duplicating the commit message is a organisational policy for the specific repository which I can't change.